# Accidentally removed dev-libs/mpc from Gentoo

Tags: gentoo, libraries, gcc

It seems I accidentally removed `dev-libs/mpc` instead of `media-sound/mpc`. Now I can't compile anything (including a replacement `dev-libs/mpc`) because in doing so I apparently murdered GCC.

How does one fix something like this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a chance if your current linked library version matches the one in stage3 archives,

Download the current stage3 files, extract it, and copy the libmpc* to /usr/lib

(confirm all needed files with `qlist` command)

Then re-emerge dev-libs/mpc with emerge, which will replace the copied libmpc files.

Comment: Thanks! I ended up discovering a thing called Tinderbox which  is basically a binary repo (see my answer), and then the process was pretty much exactly as you describe to get a compiled version back :)

Answer (score 3):

Phew, not so bad after all. Recording here for posterity, and for the next time I do this.

1. edit `make.conf`, add the line:
   `PORTAGE_BINHOST="http://tinderbox.dev.gentoo.org/default-linux/amd64/"`
2. sync the new repo: `emerge --sync`
3. install binary version: `emerge -av --binpkgonly --usepkgonly dev-libs/mpc`
4. compile source version: `emerge -av dev-libs/mpc`